# Google Cloud Storage public link download halts after 63 MB

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

(This is more like a support ticket for Google Cloud Storage Team, but I dont have a silver account so hope they see it here)

I´ve a bucket where I store websites backups.
When I need to download a copy I use the Console Storage Browser.
Just clic the file and it simply downloads, always worked.

This issue started early today: the download starts when clicking the file but halts after 63 Mb downloaded aprox and does the same every time I try.
I tried to download directly from a server, it halts.
I tried checking "public link", it halts.

Any help is really appreciated
thanks

#### Snapshots:

#### moment when it halts (using chrome browser) - loop

i.gyazo.com/1b60b80afb8c9bb9ebe2bdb764ac3bd1.gif

#### moment when it halts (from a server) - loop

i.gyazo.com/70cef9da2ed6a979fe0d0b929c40a962.gif

#### public link tested

storage.googleapis.com/cftest/dummy_file_184mb.gz

Comment: Have you tried using the gsutil tool [1] to download the files to see if it works ?

[1] https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp

Comment: Is your bucket type nearline (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/nearline) by any chance. I was able to reproduce this issue with nearline buckets.

Comment: Yes its a nearline bucket type, is this issue acceptable for nearline types?

Comment: Faizan, many thanks for your reply.
With gsutil it seems to work, so far I´ve been able to download 600Mb of a 1.5Gb file. Although it seems slower than from downloaded from browser.

Comment: Storage Browser it´s working again, thanks Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm glad to know that gsutil worked. You can use the command line for now as a workaround.

The issue with the developer console download for nearline buckets has been reported to Google engineers. You can subscribe to this issue [link](https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/detail?can=2&q=205&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Resource%20Service%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Log&id=205) to get updates.

Comment: Hi Faizan, great, I really appreciate your reply, many thanks.